# FileDialog shows no files

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have this code in **main.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Test")

    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog
        folder: shortcuts.home
        visible: true
        title: "Please choose an image"
        nameFilters: ["Image files (*.jpg *.png)", "All files (*)"]
        onAccepted: {
            image.source = fileDialog.fileUrl
        }
    }

    Image {
        id: image
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

When I run it by pressing Run in QtCreator, I get a file dialog with no files listed.

Screenshot 1

[image]

It lists files if I run it as `qmlscene-qt5 main.qml`, but this way I have no filters available (All Files only).

Screenshot 2

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make it visible when the item has been completely created:

```
FileDialog {
    id: fileDialog
    folder: shortcuts.home
    // visible: true <--- ---
    title: "Please choose an image"
    nameFilters: [ "Image files (*.jpg *.png)", "All files (*)" ]
    onAccepted: {
        image.source = fileDialog.fileUrl
    }
    Component.onCompleted: visible = true // <--- +++
}
```